# MySQL Stored Procedure 'range' as input parameter, cannot access the value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've just found an interesting problem with Stored Procedure at a new company I have recently joined.

See below, the table `pxvehiclehistory` has a column called `range`. Range is a reserved word in MySQL so the developer surrounded it with back ticks. All good stuff, apart from when the insert is executed the `range` column is always null.

As this stored procedure is simply executing an insert I've moved it into our code and my boss is off my back.

I was wondering, is it possible to even get the value of the `range` in parameter?

```
CREATE `pxvehiclehistory_insert`(
in       pxvehiclehistoryid    char(38),
in       regno                 varchar(50),
in       makeid                char(38),
in       modelid               char(38),
in       rangeid                  char(38),
in       derivativeid          char(38),
in       colour                varchar(50),
in       transmissionid        char(38),
in       fueltypeid            char(38),
in       customerid            char(38),
in       enginesize            varchar(50),
in       engineno              varchar(50),
in       dfr                   datetime,
in       createdby             char(38),
in       noofdoors             varchar(50),
in       vinno                 varchar(100),
in       createddatetime       datetime,
in       make                 varchar(50),
in       model                 varchar(50),
in       derivative                 varchar(100),
in       `range`                 varchar(50)
           )
BEGIN
    insert into pxvehiclehistory
    (       pxvehiclehistoryid   
           ,regno
           ,makeid
           ,modelid
           ,rangeid
           ,derivativeid
           ,colourid
           ,transmissionid
           ,fueltypeid
           ,customerid
           ,enginesize
           ,engineno
           ,dfr
           ,noofdoors
           ,vinno
           ,createddatetime
           ,createdby
           ,make
           ,model
           ,derivative
           ,`range`

    )
    values
    (
      pxvehiclehistoryid
     ,regno
     ,makeid
     ,modelid
     ,rangeid
     ,derivativeid
     ,(select colourid from colour where upper(description)=upper(colour))
     ,transmissionid
     ,fueltypeid
     ,customerid
     ,enginesize
     ,engineno
     ,dfr
     ,noofdoors
     ,vinno
     ,createddatetime
     ,createdby
     ,make
    ,model
    ,derivative
    ,`range`
    );

END
```

Comment: Of course it is null!!! You are inserting the previous value (which most likely is initially null). See that you are specifying in the values the word **range** with back-tilted quotes, which is telling MySQL to insert the previous value of the column which is of course null. Try inserting `'test'` instead.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read correctly your question. Try removing the back quotes around `range` in the list of values for the insert.